# The Messed Up Family and the Lost Brother

Tags: riddle, story

> My dear brother,
>
> It has been almost nine years since we lost you. We’re a big family so
>   losing just one may not seem like much of a loss but it has left a
>   hole nonetheless. You’re still here in spirit – in fact, people keep
>   forgetting you’re no longer part of our family – but it’s not the
>   same. You were always kind of out there but we all cared about you. I
>   don’t think anybody else has written yet and I’m sorry for that. I
>   can’t make up for their lack of action but I feel like, if anyone is
>   going to keep this family together, it has to be me. Even though I was
>   adopted into this family and never really matched the rest of you, I
>   feel like I must be the leader.
>
> If my nephew would ever slow down to think about it, I’m sure he’d
>   write, too. He’s always been our main line of communication. You know
>   how he is, though, always in a hurry. His dad – our big brother – is
>   still trying to apologize for him but, at this point, it doesn’t
>   really feel sincere. He’s cold-natured on the outside but I believe
>   there’s still some warmth in there, deep down. Those two have been
>   distant for so long that I don’t know if they’ll ever really get
>   along. I still find myself having to stay between them. Even his
>   “daughter” has to stand between them. (You remember why I say
>   “daughter” in quotes, right? We’re still not sure if she’s his or
>   dad’s. Gods, our family is so messed up…) Of course, it only gets
>   worse when his other son decides to get involved. He’s always stirring
>   up trouble.
>
> Granddad is still kickin’ around out there somewhere. He’s a pretty
>   icy guy but he means well. I think dad and even some of our brothers
>   try to be like him but he’s still the undisputed master of the cold
>   shoulder. He and I barely talk, really. I feel kind of guilty about it
>   – I feel like I should get to know my whole adopted family better –
>   but the trip to go see him is just so costly that it’s hard to justify
>   it most of the time.
>
> Listen, I know you’re pretty far out there most of the time but I
>   don’t want you forgetting where you belong. I don’t care what others
>   say, you still belong in this family. I know at least one of our
>   brothers is out near you once in a while. He’s still a little wet
>   behind the ears despite his age but he’ll try to swing by. Try to say
>   hi sometime, OK? Maybe send a letter?
>
> All the love in the world,
>
> Sis

**Primary Question:** Who is writing the letter and to whom are they writing it? (Get the tick)

**Bonus Question:** Can you name all the family members mentioned? (Get +1)

- Letter writer
- The brothers
- The nephew
- The daughter
- Dad and Granddad

Comment: Oh, I think I get it. Don't have the time to put the pieces together though.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh Yeah. I get it too, but it would take a lot of knowledge, or a lot of Googling to write up the answer. Not going to bother. I'll just leave it to someone else.

Comment: Does the letter follow the rules of grammar? Specifically, are people's first name capitalized always? Also, are the names explicitly written in the letter, or is this a lateral thinking puzzle?

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh OK, so that's fair. I didn't think about the work required to answer. Check the edit.

Comment: @Aura OK, so that's fair. I didn't think about the work required to answer. Check the edit.

Comment: @n00b I did not pay attention to name capitalization as I wrote the letter.

Comment: so is "Bro" a name, or a family relation? If Bro is a name, then Bro is writing the letter, to his brother.

Comment: @n00b Fair point. No, "Bro" is not the letter writer's name. It was simply a way of signing the letter without giving away a name. All family members have very specific names.

Comment: I love this puzzle.  Very creative and fun!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The family is composed of

> The planets and the mostly Greco-Roman gods for whom they were named

The brothers are

> Jupiter(Zeus), Pluto(Hades), and Neptune(Poseidon) ( the god of the ocean - "wet behind the ears despite his age")

The lost brother is

> Pluto, whose celestial body was deemed not a planet in 2005, almost 9 years ago; among the most distant planets from the sun, it was always kind of 'out there'

The letter writer is

> The Earth, named not for a Roman deity but a Germanic one, hence "adopted" and not matching the rest, but as the only populated planet the only one able to 'keep the family together' - also identified in the Greek pantheon with Gaia, whose union with Uranus gave birth to the titans - and she sends 'all the love in the world' -- literally!

Dad and Granddad are

> Saturn(Cronus), the father of the Olympians, and his father Uranus, the cold(warm?) gas giants who are 'distant'

The daughter is

> Venus, who is variously identified as the daughter of Neptune(Poseidon) and of Jupiter(Zeus)

The nephew who is "our main line of communication" is

> Mercury(Hermes), the messenger of the gods.  In astrology, the planet Mercury governs communication; it is the planet that orbits and rotates fastest

The son that's always stirring up trouble is likely

> Mars, the god of war

Comment: There seem to be some inconsitencies in the letter - if I try to map the family tree to everything that's said I end up with some crossed lines...

Comment: I agree with @pacoverflow - This is *close*, but I think there's something off.

Comment: Are you sure you've accounted for the entire family?

Comment: Toast, am I wrong about the identity of the letter writer?  Because he seems to speak of himself in the third person.  Signing the letter "Bro" means he is one of the brothers, correct?

Comment: I have my own guess for the letter writer, but my guess doesn't have any brothers...

Comment: If I'm on the right track, the only family member who is missing would probably not address her great-grandson as brother, nor sign herself as "Bro"...  But yeah something seems a little off

Comment: @dennisdeems Ah, well, hrm, right. I started out with everyone being brothers until I got on to the Roman / Greek name scheme. The name I was thinking of didn't have a gender and matches your latest edit. However, it has other names with a feminine tilt. Corrections will ensue!

Comment: Ok, I will edit my answer accordingly :)

Comment: To improve the puzzle: Would this be better with the letter write being "Earth" as would fit with what we actually call the planets or "Terra" as would fit with the Roman pantheon?

Comment: Dang. I'd *thought* about the Earth being the letter writer (after finally discarding Helios, due to lack of brothers), but I couldn't figure out the connection that would make Jupiter "big brother".  I was toying with Neptune when this got accepted.  Nice job, dennisdeems.

Comment: EngineerToast  It's probably fine as it stands.  The reference to being adopted and not fitting with the others is a strong clue that I really didn't pick up on.  I was misled for a while, but a good puzzle /should/ mislead to some extent.  It's really a well-made piece.  Bobson, pacoverflow thanks for your comments helping me to the right solution!

Comment: @EngineerToast - I'd change the signature from `Bro`.  Other than that, I think it's fine as stands.

Comment: @Bobson I merged the traits of gods and planets. Jupiter is the big brother because the planet is physically the largest. Uranus/ Granddad is the master of the cold shoulder because the planet has the coldest atmosphere in the solar system.

Comment: Just as a side note (old, I know) but Rot13(Irahf vf rvgure Whcvgre'f be *Henahf'f* qnhtugre, abg Arcghar'f (urapr, uvf be *uvf qnq'f* (nygubhtu "tenaqnq" jbhyq unir orra orggre)))